# Angular-cli : Launch time is too slow

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Need to improve my Angular2 application Launch time. At preset it's taking 10-12 seconds to launch.

There are multiple modules in the application and each modules are loaded using lazy loading.

Here's my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "AppStore-cli",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.3.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.0",
    "angular2-moment": "1.2.0",
    "angular2-select": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "autotable": "1.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "jspdf": "1.3.2",
    "jspdf-autotable": "2.3.1",
    "md2": "0.0.16",
    "ng2-auto-complete": "0.10.9",
    "ng2-pagination": "2.0.0",
    "ng2-slimscroll": "1.2.1",
    "ng2-toastr": "1.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.3.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

**angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "name": "AppStore-cli"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "./images/"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "css/indigo-pink.css",
        "css/admin.css",
        "../node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
        "../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js",
        "../node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jspdf-autotable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using following command to make build

```
ng build --prod
```

Here's the screensort of the files generation after completion of build.

[image]
Here's the screensort of load time.

[image]

Can anybody help me with how i can reduce the launch time to 2-3 seconds or less than than?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are few thing you could do:

- run `ng build -prod -aot --stats-json`
- fix any error you might have (and rebuild)
- install [webpack-bundle-analyze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) `npm install --save-dev webpack-bundle-analyzer`
- run `webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json`
- look at your bundles and remove any unnecessary code
- install compression (`gzip`) on your server (this alone should reduce vendor bundle to ~400kb)

If thing are still slow, look into server side rendering with universal, service and web workers... Google can help (;

Also consider upgrading to angular `4.0.0`. It generates less code then `2.x.x`.

Comment: It's giving the error on ng build -prod -aot --stats-json

ERROR in Unexpected value 'Ng2PaginationModule' imported by the module 

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in 
 @ ./src/main.ts 7:29-76
 @ multi ./src/main.ts



tried many ways to solve but its still there. Don't know why it is for

Comment: @PinankLakhani Yea, you can expect errors if you didn't write AoT-friendly code. It can be annoying (: If I remember correctly this particular error happens when you didn't import a module somewhere. Not sure tho', those errors are pretty bad, specially in `2.x.x`.